# Testing Controllers In Play Framework

Tags: java, unit-testing, playframework, mocking, integration-testing

I am using Play Framework and using Java as the language of choice. I have a Controller which makes a REST call to an external service. I intend to mock the external service, so that I can test the functionality of my controller. To achieve this, I have created my test cases as shown below (sample). I am embedding a server within my test to mock the external service.

```
public class SomeControllerTest extends WithApplication {

private static Server SERVER;

@Override
protected Application provideApplication() {
    final Module testModule = new AbstractModule() {
        @Override
        public void configure() {
            bind(AppDao.class).to(MockAppDaoImpl.class);
        }
    };
    return new GuiceApplicationBuilder().in(Environment.simple()).overrides(testModule).build();
}

@BeforeClass
public static void setup() {
    Router router = new RoutingDsl()
            .POST("/api/users")
            .routeTo(() -> created())
            .build();
    SERVER = Server.forRouter(router, 33373);
    PORT = SERVER.httpPort();
}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDown() {
    SERVER.stop();
}

@Test
public void testCreateUser() {
    ObjectNode obj = Json.newObject();
    obj.put("name", "John Doe");
    obj.put("email", "john.doe@example.com");
    Http.RequestBuilder request = new Http.RequestBuilder()
            .method(POST)
            .bodyJson(obj)
            .uri("/some/url/here");
    Result result = route(request);
    assertEquals(ERR_MSG_STATUS_CODE, CREATED, result.status());
    assertEquals(ERR_MSG_CONTENT_TYPE, Http.MimeTypes.JSON, result.contentType().get());
}
```

My expectation is that when I run the test, the mock server would run and based on my application's test configuration, my controller will make a call to the mock server which would return `201` and my test case would pass.
But, this doesn't happen, because as soon as `setup()` method completes, the mock server is killed, and my controller cannot make a call to it.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe you can use `Helpers.testServer();` to get the server and then `Helpers.start(server);` to start one.

Comment: @Kris how would I provide the Router to the test server created by the Helpers?

Comment: Sorry, never tried it with an Router.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Testing of controller should be rather done by inheritance from `WithApplication`

```java
public class TestController extends WithApplication {
   @Test  
   public void testSomething() {  
       Helpers.running(Helpers.fakeApplication(), () -> {  
           // put test stuff  
           // put asserts  
       });
   }  
}
```

In order to test a controller method use Helpers.fakeRequest and reverse routing.
The external service may be just mocked with mockito or other mocking framework you like.

You can find [here](http://www.codepreference.com/2016/06/unit-testing-powermock-mocking-play.html) several examples.

Comment: Thank you for your input and for the link. I will have to try it out. Once I find it working as expected I'll mark it as correct answer.